# How to store user input locally using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-platform

I'm creating a cross-platform app and I want the user **bio** to be stored **locally and stay there after refresh and close/reopen**.
*Thanks*

```js
var newBio = document.getElementById("bio").value;
var storeBio = localStorage.setItem(newBio);
document.getElementById("bio").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(storeBio);
```

```html
<input id="bio" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Bio" onmouseout="showBotNav(); saveBio()"><br>
```

Comment: You're using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) incorrectly.

Comment: Oh ok. What do you use to store something like this locally?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the the [examle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example) in MDN documentation or elsewhere if you don't know how to write something.

`.getItem` needs a name as an argument. And `.setItem` needs two (name and value) but you provided only one argument `storeBio` wich is incorrect( also because function `localStorage.setItem`
can't be a name).

In your html you declared saveBio function. Why not show us save and get functions as is?

```js
function saveBio() {
  var newBio = document.getElementById("bio").value;
  localStorage.setItem('bio', newBio);
}

function getBio() {
  // why you were using (correct way) ".value" when setting bio
  // but here you are using .innerHTML ?
  document.getElementById("bio") //.innerHTML =      
    .value = localStorage.getItem('bio')

  // by the way innerHTML is only present on elements with closing tag. Input element is not one of 
}

// here you calling function when page is loaded
getBio()
```

```html
<input id="bio" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Bio" onmouseout="showBotNav(); saveBio()"><br>
```

The posted question indicates that you did not include [enough effort to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your problem. We are always glad to help and support new coders here on SO but you need to help yourself first.